# Difference between stb_loadimage() and raster.getPixels() of java for same file

Tags: java, c++, c++11

I wrote two codes to get image data. One from java and one from c++.

C++ code:

```cpp
unsigned char *data1 = stbi_load("C:/Users/skss/Pictures/Untitled.png", &width1, &height1, &nrChannels1, 0);
```

And for java:

```java
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File    ("C:/Users/skss/Pictures/Untitled.png"));
Raster ras=img.getRaster();
double[] data=new double[img.getWidth()*img.getHeight()*3];
ras.getPixels(0,0,img.getWidth(),img.getHeight(),data);
```

But these two not producing same results.

Here is the image:

[image: sri]

How data is arranged in GL_RGB. ie. byte *data={R,G,B,R,G,B}; or other type?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the picture that you are using?

Comment: In Java you are using `double[]` and in C++ you are using `unsigned char *`. This is a strong sign that the formats they use are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

They are 2 completely different implementations.

stbi_load is giving you a raw byte array, each byte representing a R G B value. Like you said, the format of the data would be {R,G,B,R,G,B...}, every three bytes representing an actual pixel. The java version is giving you an array of doubles, presumably in the same format, just with a different data type.

As for opengl, you need to tell it the format of the pixel data, and the actual data type you are giving it. In the c++ version, it would be GL_RGB as the format, and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE as the type, where as in the java version it would be GL_RGB still as the format, but the data type would be GL_FLOAT (or GL_DOUBLE)